# GCP - GKE: Every Ingress configuration keeps resetting automatically. How to set an HTTPS health check?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I know that Ingress requires a service in an healthy state in order to serve its contents through HTTP(S) and to do so I configured a ReadinessProbe on my workload deployment:

```
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /api/healthz
            port: 4400
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 20
```

Essentially, I have a webserver that serves HTTPS requests on port `4400` and I configured a `healthz` resource to return an HTTP 200 response. My webserver is listening for incoming connections on ports:

- HTTP -> 4300
- HTTPS -> 4400

Now, in order to access those ports I have a GKE Service (`myService`) that targets the webserver and in particular:

```
  ports:
  - name: port-1
    nodePort: 31277
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4300
  - name: port-2
    nodePort: 32167
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4400
```

Now, if I create a new Ingress service (`myIngress`) related to `myService` GCP gives me back this Kubernetes configuration:

```
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-service
    servicePort: port-2
  rules:
 - host: test-domain-name-here.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: port-2
  tls:
 - secretName: letsencrypt-custom-cert
```

As you can see here it's targeting the servicePort `port-2`:

[image]

GKE created (automatically) a new backend service for this ingress configuration named `k8s-be-32167--XXXX`, which targets the `port-2` `32167`, and most importantly a *Default kubernetes L7 Loadbalancing health check* that should monitor the health status - the *readiness* - of the service.

The problem is that this health check should test the port `32167` using HTTPS and not HTTP and **whenever I try to set this health check for HTTPS after a couple of minutes GCP resets everything to its defaults which is utterly annoying!!!**

Comment: On HTTP->HTTPS traffic redirection: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49667738/1977778, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126128/1977778, https://blog.realkinetic.com/http-to-https-using-google-cloud-load-balancer-dda57ac97c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently target pools only allow HTTP health checks, and the legacy style at that, you can take a look into this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#lb_guide) that shows the health check concepts and protocols allowed.

Also, I found this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/136590544) where you can follow up and put your comments to know when HTTPS is going to be allowed / supported for health checks.

Comment: Thank you @Augustin. At the end I configured Ingress to target primarily HTTP (port 80), and the health check created by GCP is now checking my WS through HTTP. It's also serving HTTPS correctly, but in my opinion this approach is very confusing for the end users. For instance, the health check configuration UI lets you choose between HTTPS and HTTP. They should, at the very least, add a warning explaining that this is not going to work.